# How do I create a release configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image]

I found the configuration manager, created a new configuration, but then under the "Configuration" column in the Configuration Manager I still only have one configuration?? So where do I modify the *real* configurations?

Every time I run my app I get this annoying prompt:

[image]

I don't *want* to enable debugging!

Comment: So why not run it through `Debug-> Start Without Debugging` (Ctrl-F5)?

Comment: @Blachshma: That's an extra key :-) There has to be a way to create a release configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue.  Just upgraded a project into VS2012 but when I choose the Release configuration and try to choose "Release" as the configuration for the main project in my solution it only has "Debug" as a choice.  I made sure my web.config didn't have anything enabled for debug only.  Is there any other place I should be looking?

I just found this searching on Bing and it seems to explain why.  My main project is a Web Site Project which apparently doesn't have the notion of debug and release being different.  If that's the case they should have called it release instead of debug in my opinion.

Here's the link:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1845650.aspx/1?vs+2012+web+deployment+